# Why does glut.h pop up with a bunch of undefined references in CodeBlocks?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, gcc

I am trying to understand something here. If I build the first program from OpenGL Game Programming and run it in Release Mode everything works. I get the cube rendered in an OpenGL window. But if I compile and run in Debug Mode, glut.h pops up, with a huge list of undefined references. I know something is wrong here, I shouldn't have to alter a library file, so I want to figure this out. Here are all the errors:

```
||=== Build: Debug in chapter1 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj\Debug\chapter1.o||In function `glutInit_ATEXIT_HACK':|
H:\AllCode\include\glut.h|486|undefined reference to `__glutInitWithExit@12'|
obj\Debug\chapter1.o||In function `glutCreateWindow_ATEXIT_HACK':|
H:\AllCode\include\glut.h|503|undefined reference to `__glutCreateWindowWithExit@8'|
obj\Debug\chapter1.o||In function `glutCreateMenu_ATEXIT_HACK':|
H:\AllCode\include\glut.h|549|undefined reference to `__glutCreateMenuWithExit@8'|
obj\Debug\chapter1.o||In function `main':|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|71|undefined reference to `glutInitDisplayMode@4'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|74|undefined reference to `glutInitWindowSize@8'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|75|undefined reference to `glutInitWindowPosition@8'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|81|undefined reference to `glutDisplayFunc@4'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|82|undefined reference to `glutReshapeFunc@4'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|83|undefined reference to `glutMouseFunc@4'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|84|undefined reference to `glutKeyboardFunc@4'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|85|undefined reference to `glutIdleFunc@4'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|89|undefined reference to `glutMainLoop@0'|
obj\Debug\chapter1.o||In function `Z10Initializev':|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|102|undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|102|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|108|undefined reference to `glutSetMenu@4'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|109|undefined reference to `glutAddMenuEntry@8'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|110|undefined reference to `glutAttachMenu@4'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|134|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|134|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'|
obj\Debug\chapter1.o||In function `Z12MouseHandleriiii':|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|156|undefined reference to `glutPostRedisplay@0'|
obj\Debug\chapter1.o||In function `Z15KeyboardHandlerhii':|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|177|undefined reference to `glutPostRedisplay@0'|
obj\Debug\chapter1.o||In function `Z15MainMenuHandleri':|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|197|undefined reference to `glutPostRedisplay@0'|
obj\Debug\chapter1.o||In function `Z7Animatev':|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|208|undefined reference to `glutPostRedisplay@0'|
obj\Debug\chapter1.o||In function `Z7Displayv':|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|275|undefined reference to `glutSwapBuffers@0'|
obj\Debug\chapter1.o||In function `Z11LoadTexturePcRj':|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|287|undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|287|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|292|undefined reference to `auxDIBImageLoadA@4'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|311|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|313|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'|
obj\Debug\chapter1.o||In function `Z9DrawScene12rendermode_t':|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|323|undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|323|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|389|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|389|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|389|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|389|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'|
obj\Debug\chapter1.o||In function `Z8DrawCubev':|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|399|undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|399|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|462|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|462|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'|
obj\Debug\chapter1.o||In function `Z11DrawSurfacev':|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|472|undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|472|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|510|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|510|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'|
obj\Debug\chapter1.o||In function `ZN11CHiResTimer17GetElapsedSecondsEm':|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\HiResTimer.h|47|undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\HiResTimer.h|47|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\HiResTimer.h|59|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\HiResTimer.h|59|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'|
obj\Debug\chapter1.o||In function `ZN11CHiResTimer6GetFPSEm':|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\HiResTimer.h|70|undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\HiResTimer.h|70|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\HiResTimer.h|84|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'|
||More errors follow but not being shown.|
||Edit the max errors limit in compiler options...|
||=== Build failed: 50 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

There is something weird going on here... I don't have AllCode linked to this anywhere. I have nothing in the Linker or Search Directory settings. So how come AllCode is being referenced? Where is it getting that information and how do I change it?

As I understand it, I need to get this thing to compile and run in Debug AND Release Modes, that way all errors are addressed. Do I have this wrong?

My system is Windows 7 64-bit. However I am running Code::Blocks 13.12 32-bit. I have installed the non-MinGW version, then installed MinGW (also 32-bit) and linked Code::Blocks to that. Using MinGW GCC compiler, g++ for c++, building for 32-bit.

Into the MinGW\bin directory I have placed OpenGL32.dll and the other OpenGL dlls. Into MinGW\Include\GL I have copied over the OpenGL .h files. Have I done something wrong here?

I want to understand how to set things up correctly, so that I can compile and run any OpenGL code, even if its 20 years old or so. I don't know the right way to go about doing this. I would appreciate some advice and help.

UPDATE:
So I have a libglut32win.a file I found, and either adding it or, under Compiler/Linker Settings/Other Linker Options typing in -lglut32win, stops glut from popping up with errors. Instead I get these:

```
||=== Build: Debug in chapter1 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj\Debug\chapter1.o||In function `Z10Initializev':|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|102|undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|102|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|134|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|134|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'|
obj\Debug\chapter1.o||In function `Z11LoadTexturePcRj':|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|287|undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|287|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|292|undefined reference to `auxDIBImageLoadA@4'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|311|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|313|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'|
obj\Debug\chapter1.o||In function `Z9DrawScene12rendermode_t':|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|323|undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|323|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|389|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|389|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|389|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|389|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'|
obj\Debug\chapter1.o||In function `Z8DrawCubev':|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|399|undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|399|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|462|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|462|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'|
obj\Debug\chapter1.o||In function `Z11DrawSurfacev':|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|472|undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|472|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|510|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\chapter1.cpp|510|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'|
obj\Debug\chapter1.o||In function `ZN11CHiResTimer17GetElapsedSecondsEm':|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\HiResTimer.h|47|undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\HiResTimer.h|47|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\HiResTimer.h|59|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\HiResTimer.h|59|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'|
obj\Debug\chapter1.o||In function `ZN11CHiResTimer6GetFPSEm':|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\HiResTimer.h|70|undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\HiResTimer.h|70|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Register'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\HiResTimer.h|84|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'|
H:\My Documents\Coding\OpenGL\chapter1\HiResTimer.h|84|undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'|
||=== Build failed: 31 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

So what does this mean?

Comment: I forget the exact ins-and-outs of it now, as it was such a long time ago. However, I had (I think) similar problems when I first tried Glut stuff with C::B under windows (possibly linux too, I forget) The solution for me was to download and use the glut replacement, freeglut. You can find it here: http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/ **EDIT:** Just checked the CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib folder- there is no file name libglut.a - that would be why I installed freeglut - glut's lib files aren't available with the C::B install. (probably a minGW thing) Anyhow, freeglut works for me. Dont forget to link it!

Answer (score 0):

Those are standard errors received when you haven't linked to a library.  It's likely your Release build settings have an entry for linking to glut but the Debug build settings do not.  If you want a library to link in both Release and Debug you need to add it at the project level rather than the build level.